# Placing multiple Icons in Jquery mobile Header

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app using Cordova and JQMobile . I have to place 5 icons on the header without any text.But I am able to place only two per line as per the example on jqm demos page.Also the icons are displayed in seperate boxes  rather than being displayed in the header itself.

What i want is   http://tinypic.com/r/2qi5u6q/8

what i get is http://tinypic.com/r/ap777m/8

I have spent a lot of time and need someone's help

Comment: Please share your HTML markup here

Comment: You are using the data-role="header", why don't you try with your "own" div ?